# Changing the search widget link icon

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, flex, arcgis-flex-viewer

I want to change the pre-defined red arrow link icon in the search widget to another icon:

[image: screen shot]

Where would I do this? It looks like the widget is drawing from the InfoPopupWidget.swf?

Comment: do you have a link? - its easier to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success! After re-compiling the Search Widget components: SearchResultItemRenderer.mxml, swf.,  .xml, and SearchWidget.swf.

Also had to adjust picture size in SearchResultItemRenderer.mxml in code here:
[image: line 115]

as well as here:
[image: line 135]

Answer (score 2):

This is not configurable with the compiled version of the [ArcGIS Viewer for Flex.](http://links.esri.com/flexviewer)

Assuming that you are a Flex developer, already familiar with and working with the source code, and using the latest version (currently 2.3.1). The relevant file is widgets/SearchWidget/SearchResultItemRenderer.mxml and at the bottom of that file is where the source property is set to a specific image (w_link.png):

```
<mx:Image width="18" height="18"
          buttonMode="true"
          click="showLink(event)"
          includeInLayout="{searchResult.link != null}"
          source="assets/images/w_link.png"
          toolTip="{searchResult.link}"
          useHandCursor="true"
          visible="{searchResult.link != null}"/>
```

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapps/flexviewer/help/index.html#/Search_widget/01m300000023000000/

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are using the flex sample viewer.
And talking about the search results tab/button on that widget.
If that is true you would need either the adobe Flashbuilder, or [another product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash) to "rebuild" the swf.
There are some [open source solutions](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=open+source+swf&aq=f&aqi=g5&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=3ab7b119eb13be61&biw=1132&bih=629) to this task.
BTW: the infopopupwidget handles the popups when you select an object from the search. The C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\flexviewer\widgets\Search\searchWidget.swf handles the actual search popup.
BTW2: I don't get the red arrow in my 2.3.1 viewer.
search results screenshot here -